# How to get attributes from multiple levels of XML doc using R script

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I am looking for a way to use xpath to extract attributes from nodes and their children (potentially multiple levels down the hierarchy) into a table-like structure.

Below code shows an example document and the desired result.

All details are in the code below.

```
require(XML)

# Generating example file
xmlstring <- "<CATALOG>
 <CD title='Great hooks' id='1'>
  <ARTISTS>
   <ARTIST type='composer' name='Peter Pan' id='11'>
    <INFO age='118'/>
   </ARTIST>
   <ARTIST type='singer' name='Tinkerbelle' id='12'>
    <INFO age='118'/>
   </ARTIST>
  </ARTISTS>
 </CD>
 <CD title='The Planets' id='2'>
  <ARTISTS>
   <ARTIST type='composer' name='Clyde Tombaugh' id='21'>
    <INFO age='91'/>
   </ARTIST>
   <ARTIST type='singer' name='Johann Galle' id='22'>
    <INFO age='207'/>
   </ARTIST>
   <ARTIST type='singer' name='Urbain Le Verrier' id='23'>
    <INFO age='208'/>
   </ARTIST>
  </ARTISTS>
 </CD>
 <CD title='45 Minutes Silence' id='3'>
  <ARTISTS>
   <ARTIST type='composer' name='John Cale' id='31'>
    <INFO age='77'/>
   </ARTIST>
  </ARTISTS>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>"

file.name <- "testxmlfile.xml"

writeChar(xmlstring, file.name)

# Reading example file using XML::xmlParse
doc <- xmlParse(file.name)

# I need a data frame or similar table structure with columns CD.title, Singer.name
# and Singer.age where 'Singer' is any artist with @type='singer'

# I can get the CD titles like this:
CD.titles <- xpathSApply(doc, "/CATALOG/CD", xmlGetAttr, "title")
# Singer names like this:
Singer.names <- xpathSApply(doc, "/CATALOG/CD/ARTISTS/ARTIST[@type='singer']", xmlGetAttr, "name")
# Singer ages like this:
Singer.ages <- xpathSApply(doc, "/CATALOG/CD/ARTISTS/ARTIST[@type='singer']/INFO", xmlGetAttr, "age")

# But how do I put them all together, taking into account the number of singers
# per CD is variable (and may be 0)?

# I am not interested in CDs without singer, so if there is no singer either the
# CD may be entirely omitted or Singer.name/Singer.age may be NA

# Desired result:
# CD.title                   | Singer.name         | Singer.age
# ===========================| ====================| ==========
# Great hooks                | Tinkerbelle         | 118
# The Planets                | Johann Galle        | 207
# The Planets                | Urbain Le Verrier   | 208

# Thanks in advance for suggestions.
```

Totally unnecessary spam because I apparently can't post this without typing enough outside the code box regardless of the fact that it contains all the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to do the following:

1. Create an empty `data.frame`, say `df`
2. Loop through **CD** nodes
3. For each **CD**, get the *title* attribute and the **singer** node(s)
4. For each **singer**, if any, get the *name* and *age* attributes
5. Add each row to the `df`

As follows:

```
df <- data.frame()

CDs <- xpathSApply(doc, "/CATALOG/CD")

for (CD in CDs) {
  title <- xpathSApply(CD, ".", xmlGetAttr, "title")
  Singers <- xpathSApply(CD, "ARTISTS/ARTIST[@type='singer']")
  name <- NA
  age <- NA
  for(singer in Singers){
    name <- xpathSApply(singer, '.', xmlGetAttr, "name")
    age <- xpathSApply(singer, './INFO', xmlGetAttr, "age")
    df <- rbind(df, list(title=title, name=name, age=age),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }
}
```

Output of `df`:

```
#        title                    name   age
#1  Great hooks            Tinkerbelle   118
#2  The Planets           Johann Galle   207
#3  The Planets      Urbain Le Verrier   208
```

I may update the answer later with a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looping through the records is something I was hoping to avoid. The actual documents I am working with are very large and contain up to a million elements, so I was hoping to find a way to get the values from both the //CD and //CD/ARTISTS/ARTIST level in a single xpath query.

Comment: @BeamerMiasma I don't know `r`, but could something like `//CD/(let $a:=@title return ARTISTS/ARTIST[@type='singer']/join(($a,@name,INFO/@age),' | '))` be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea provided in the previous answer, I am here using two nested `lapply` instead of the `for` loops. Please note that you need to install `dplyr` (if not already installed).

```
result.df <- dplyr::bind_rows(unlist(lapply(xpathSApply(doc, "//CD"), function(cd){
  lapply(xpathSApply(cd, ".//ARTIST[@type='singer']"), function(singer){
    data.frame(t(c(xpathSApply(cd, "./@title"), xpathSApply(singer, './@name|./INFO/@age'))), stringsAsFactors = F)
  })
}), recursive = F))
```

Hope it helps.